# foreach loop is not working(parallelization)

Tags: performance, r, foreach, parallel-processing

If I want to speed up the following code, How can I do that?

```
pcg <- foreach(boot.iter=1:boot.rep） %dopar% {
d.boot<-d[in.sample[[boot.iter]],]
```

*here in.sample[[boot.iter]] randomly generates 1000 row numbers.

I planned to split the overall tasks and send the seperated trials to each core. for example,

```
sub_task<-foreach(i=1:cores.use)%dopar%{
for (j in 1:trialsPerCore){
d.boot<-d[in.sample[[structure[i,j]]],]}}
```

*structure is a matrix which contains from 1 to boot.rep

But this one would not work, seems like we cannot use "for" loop inside the foreach? Also, the d.boot only keeps the last iteration of each core.

I tried to search online, I found the following code works,

```
sub_task<foreach(i=1:cores.use)%:%
foreach(j=1:trialsPerCore)%dopar%{
d.boot<-d[in.sample[[structure[i,j]]],]｝
```

But I think it is similar to my original function, and I do not think there is a great enhancement.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like `in.sample` is a function since it generates random numbers, but your use of `[[` makes it look like a vector or list.  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't look like you're doing much if any computation in your `foreach` loop.  You appear to be simply creating a list of matrices from `d`.  That wouldn't benefit from parallel computing unless you can perform an operation on those matrices in your loop, and ideally return a relatively small result from that operation.

Although "chunking" often helps to execute parallel loops more efficiently, I don't think it's going to help here.  The communication may be a little more efficient, but you're still just doing a lot of communication and essentially no computation.

Note that your attempt at chunking doesn't work because the `for` loop in the `foreach` loop is repeatedly assigning a matrix to the same variable.  Then, the `for` loop itself returns a `NULL` as the body of the `foreach` loop, so that `sub_task` is a list of NULL's.  An `lapply` would work much better in this context.

It will help a little to compute the values in the `in.sample` list in the `foreach` loop.  That will decrease the amount of data that is auto-exported to each of the workers at the cost of a bit more computation on the workers, which is generally what you want to do in parallel loops.  At the very least, you could iterate over `in.sample` directly:

```
pcg <- foreach(i=in.sample) %dopar% d[i,]
```

In this form, it's all the more obvious that there isn't enough computation to warrant parallel computing.  If there isn't any real computation to perform, you're better off using `lapply`:

```
pcg <- lapply(in.sample, function(i) d[i,])
```

Comment: I only paste a piece of code here. in.sample is a function which generates 1000 numbers(1000 rows). So it is a kind of bootstrapping.

Comment: @kevin81mvp If `in.sample` is a function, is the use of `[[` a typo? That should generate an error.

Comment: I have tried so many other alternatives (for, relicate), won't work. The reason is I wanna 100 different numbers for boot.iter, say from 1 to 100. That was why I built a matrix so that I can take out a different number each time.